# Java swing, elements get back on their initial position, after adding new one

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to write in java program which allows me to creating new controls dynamically, and to move them by mouse.
Right now I can move them, but when i'm creating new one then every object returns to its initial possition. It is quite obvious why - i'm using pack() method on mainframe, but I don't know how to do it otherwise.

Description:

- myPanel - my class which extends JPanel
- PanelList - ArrayList which contains generated panels
- addmyPanel - method shich adds new panel to PanelList
- getmyPanel - returns myPanel with certain id

  ```
  private void jButton0ActionActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      myPanel temp = new myPanel();
      addmyPanel();
      for (int i =0 ;i < PanelList.size(); i++){
          temp = PanelList.get(i);
          if (!temp.getIsActive()){
              try{
                  add(getmyPanel(temp.getId()), new Constraints(new Leading(35, 100, 10, 10), new Leading(44, 100, 12, 12)));
                  PanelList.get(i).setIsActive();
              }
              catch (NoSuchElementException e){}
          }
      }
      frame.pack();
  }
  ```

Comment: not quite sure what you are asking here. Have you tried frame.revalidate() ?

Comment: and can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Sounds like the use of an unappropriate `LayoutManager`. Make sure to use one that will "keep" the locations of your already added components.

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/15x77kp.png - program window
http://i41.tinypic.com/2rf829i.png - after clicking button 
http://i41.tinypic.com/9916ow.png - panel moved by mouse
http://i41.tinypic.com/2rf829i.jpg - clicked second time
http://i41.tinypic.com/w0gwli.png - both panels moved by mouse

i tried frame.revalidate() as you sugessted and it looks identically

And which LayoutManager could do such things? i'm quite a newbie in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Drag Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/). It won't reset the location when the layout manager is invoked.

Comment: I'd really like to try but when I use it like it is described but I get error:
`myPanel temp = new myPanel( new DragLayout() );`

DragLayout cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: That is probably because you are using myPanel and you have a custom constructor. Just use `temp.setLayout( new DragLayout() );` after you create your panel.

Comment: Yes I do use custom constructor, but setLayout method gives me the same error. I also added `super();` to my constructor, but it gave me nothing, anyway, here is my whole code, meaby now the problem will be more clear
http://pastebin.com/BwxgibWD
http://pastebin.com/S4WurtCB

Comment: Sorry it looks like you are using an IDE to generate the code and you are using custom classes for the layout manager. I don't know what that code does. You should create your GUI manually and don't rely on generated code. That way you understand the code better.

Comment: I guess that this is an answer :) Thank you